# How do I stockpile Sand?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I've just bought several bags of sand from a Trader - thought I'd play around with making some glass.

But, I cannot find the correct stockpile setting to get my sand stockpiled next to the glass furnace.

Help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default, bags of sand are stored in a Furniture Stockpile. But you can also mess with the stockpile settings (<kbd>q</kbd>, cursor over the stockpile, <kbd>s</kbd>) to restrict your stockpile to only sand. Under the "Furniture/Siege Ammo" category, sand types are under the "Metals" settings.

On another note: if there is exposed sand on your map you can tell your dwarves to gather sand (so you don't always have to buy it from a trader). You need to set up a zone over the sand on the ground and designate it for sand collection. Then, at a glass furnace, issue the collect sand task.

Comment: Ah ha! There it is. Thanks very much. I'd looked at bags under furniture, but sand wasn't under materials and I didn't bother checking in metals...

Comment: I can't explain *why* it's there. :)

Comment: *shrug* on closers inspection a lot of non-metal stone (and some gems) are in "metal", so maybe it should really be "stuff you dig"?

Comment: @DMA57361 I've noticed that. It makes it hard to do a bars stockpile as well.

Comment: And don't forget to have a stockpile near your glass kiln set to hold all of your nice empty bags for the sand gathering.

Answer (score 9):

It appears to have been moved as of 40.08 (probably earlier, but this is the first time I've tried to find it recently...)

I found it in "Furniture/Siege Ammo" => Type => "sand bags".

Comment: Of course sand bags are in the 'siege ammo' section. Maybe dorfs use them as ammo in catapults.